# Как не допустить создания "зависших" строк в многостраничном документе?

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

Мне необходимо сделать печатную форму(отчет) в котором будет выводится помимо всего прочего(*header, footer*) таблица как показано ниже в снипете.

Пользователю хочу отдавать `pdf` файл, для формирования которого использую `nuget` пакет [itextsharp](/questions/tagged/itextsharp) версии 5.5.10

Подскажите пож. как осуществить при необходимости перенос *всей* строки(*T1*,*T2* и т.п.) на новую страницу

```css
th, td{
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan = 2>T1</td>
    <td>OrderCode 1</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td rowspan = 2>Overhang</td>
    <td rowspan = 2>Runtime</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>OrderCode2</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
  </tr>
  <td rowspan = 2>T2</td>
    <td>OrderCode 3</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td rowspan = 2>Overhang</td>
    <td rowspan = 2>Runtime</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>OrderCode4</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
  </tr>
  <td rowspan = 2>T3</td>
    <td>OrderCode 4</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td rowspan = 2>Overhang</td>
    <td rowspan = 2>Runtime</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>OrderCode5</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Код создания `pdf` файла

```
using(var fs = new FileStream(path))
{
    var document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10,10,10,10);
    var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
    var table = new PdfPTable(5);

    var tools = new List<int> {1,2,3};

    for(var row = 0; row<50; row++)
    {
        table.AddCell(new PdfPTable(new Phrase($"T{row}")){Rowspan = tools.Count});
        table.AddCell($"Cutter №{tools.First()});
        table.AddCell("Vendor");
        table.AddCell(new PdfPTable(new Phrase("Overhang")){Rowspan = tools.Count});
        table.AddCell(new PdfPTable(new Phrase("Runtime")){Rowspan = tools.Count});
        foreach(var tool in tools.Skip(1))
        {
            table.AddCell($"Cutter №{tool});
            table.AddCell("Vendor");
        }
    }
    document.Add(table);
    document.Close();
    pdfWriter.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблему удалось решить следующим образом:

1. В документ добавляется не одна таблица, а на каждую группу создается новая таблица.
   1.1. Добавляем переменную счетчик в которой будет значение оставшегося свободного пространства на листе.
2. Перед добавлением таблицы в документ проверяется достаточно ли места для добавления *строки* целиком.

   2.1. Если места достаточно то добавляем *строку* в документ и уменьшаем переменную счетчик показывающую сколько свободного места осталось.

   2.2. Если места не достаточно то в документ добавляем новую страницу, *сбрасываем* переменную счетчик, добавляем строку, уменьшаем переменную на значение добавленной строки

---

```
float workspace = 0f;
float elapsed = 0f;

var random = new Random();
workspace = elapsed = document.PageSize.GetRectangle(document.Top,document.Bottom).Height;
var tools = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5};
for(var row; row<50;row++)
{    
    var _tools = tools.Take(random.Next(2,5));
    var table = new PdfPTable(5);
    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase($"T{row+1}")), {Rowspan = _tools.Count()});
    table.AddCell($"cutter #{_tools.First()}");
    table.AddCell($"Vendor");
    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("125")), {Rowspan = _tools.Count()});
    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("25")), {Rowspan = _tools.Count()});
    foreach(var tool in _tools.Skip(1))
    {
        table.AddCell($"cutter #{tool}");
        table.AddCell($"Vendor");
    }
    if (elapsed > table.TotalHeight)
    {
        document.Add(table);
        elapsed -= table.TotalHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        document.NewPage();
        document.Add(table);
        elapsed = workspace - table.TotalHeight;
    }
}
```